# How to dynamically import a json file

Tags: import, svelte, vite, template-literals

I'm trying to import a JSON file on my Vite app, whose paths are dynamically generated. So the `import` path for this JSON includes variables.

[image]

I know it's possible to do it with `require`, but I'm working with Svelte, and [I cant use requires](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4775).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dynamic `import()` statement for that. This will return a promise, which has to be awaited, though. E.g.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import meta from './meta.json';

    const filePromise = import(/* @vite-ignore */ `./${meta.file}.json`);
</script>

{#await filePromise then file}
    {file.property}
{/await}
```

There are [some limitations](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations) to dynamic imports in Vite so the application can be built properly. The `@vite-ignore` comment silences a warning output about these limitations.